# How do I sleep in JavaScript on a finite callstack

Tags: javascript

I found this neat little code for sleeping in TypeScript and JavaScript on Stack Overflow:

```
async function sleep(ms : number) {
  return new Promise<void>(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

I use it like this:

```
while(true) {
  updateBackground();
  await sleep(1000);
}
```

The potential problem is that the sleep function adds "then" to the callstack and it looks like the callstack grows bigger and bigger for each sleep call. I assume that I will run out of space on the stack sooner or later.

[image: stacktrace in chrome]

Is there a good way to solve that. How do I sleep?

Comment: Basically, you don't sleep. You use events to trigger things, not time. If you give us more information about what you are trying to solve by sleeping, rather than your sleep problem, we may be able to help solve that problem without needing to sleep.

Comment: There is not reason to really use a while loop. Just make a function and call it on an interval. That is what you basically are doing! `setInterval(updateBackground, 1000);`

Comment: Hi, the actual problem is that I want to display an image for a few seconds and the switch to another image. No input events will be sent. I use different sleep times for different images.

Comment: @epascarello That's slightly different. The sleeping loop measures the time **between** invocations, not the time from starting one invocation to starting the next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each iteration of the `while` loop should flush the call stack. Are you sure you are looking at the actual call stack?

Did you check the Developer Tools "Sources" tab's right sidebar under "Call Stack". It should report empty. It should not be growing infinitely.

In the code below, the stack should only ever be a size of three:

```js
const sleep = async (ms) =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const printTime = () => {
  console.log(`Current time: ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`);
};

const updateBackground = () => {
  printTime();
};

(async () => {
  while (true) {
    updateBackground();
    await sleep(1000);
  }
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Placing a break-point inside of `printTime` should show the following stack:

```js
updateBackground  // printTime call within updateBackground
(anonymous)       // call from within the while-loop
(anonymous)       // the top-level await or IIFE
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It looks like the callstack in sources tab is empty most of the time but why is that different from console.trace?

Comment: @JohanMattsson the trace must aggregate every call. Tracing a programs execution should essentially log everything that has happened since the program was executed.

Comment: @JohanMattsson I assume that you're seeing this in FF. It seems Chrome has very different `console.trace()` output. As far as I can tell, the trace output in FF is bounded to a certain "depth", so you won't be leaking into it.

Comment: @spender thank you, the console screenshot is from Chrome v 107.0.5304.107, I hope that chrome also prevents a stackoverflow.

Comment: Many thank for helping me debug this. I found the problem and added the solution here. TS can be a bit deceptive.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, doing a `while (true)` on Javascript is probably a bad idea.

If you have a task that should be done every second, the best way is to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval):

```
setInterval(() => {
  updateBackground();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The examples provided here did work but the problem was something different. I made a mistake assuming that async / await works in the same way in both TypeScript and JavaScript. That is not always the case.

My tsconfig.json had this setting:

```
 "target": "es2015"
```

I compiled the code for an old target and the compiler added the step/then/fulfilled calls to the code instead of returning.

This line fixed the problem:

```
"target": "es2017",
```